# There is no output to JSON file in my python script

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, database-connection

I have a python script that supposed to perform SQL queries. However the script is not writing to the JSON file and when I open the JSON file it is empty. However I get no error when the script is running. I've tried fixing this error to no avail. I would greatly appreciate your help! I added certificate_store = cursor.fetchall() but even adding that does not seem to fix my code.

**Code**

```
from __future__ import print_function

try:
    import psycopg2
except ImportError:
    raise ImportError('\n\033[33mpsycopg2 library missing. pip install psycopg2\033[1;m\n')
    sys.exit(1)

import re
import sys
import json
import pprint
import time
import psycopg2.extras

outfilepath = "crtsh_output/crtsh_flat_file"

DB_HOST = 'crt.sh'
DB_NAME = 'certwatch'
DB_USER = 'guest'

DELAY = 0


def connect_to_db():
    start = 0
    offset = 10
    flag = True

    while flag:
        filepath = 'forager.txt'
        print('am i stuck')
        with open(filepath, "at+") as fp, open(outfilepath, "wt+") as outfile:
            try:
                for cnt, domain_name in enumerate(fp):
                    print("Line {}: {}".format(cnt, domain_name))
                    print(domain_name)
                    domain_name = domain_name.rstrip()

                    SQL = '''
                        SELECT c.id, x509_commonName(c.certificate) as common_name,
                              x509_issuerName(c.certificate) as issuer_name,
                              x509_notBefore(c.certificate) as not_before,
                              x509_notAfter(c.certificate) as not_after,
                              x509_keyAlgorithm(c.certificate) as key_algorithm,
                              x509_keySize(c.certificate) as key_size,
                              x509_serialNumber(c.certificate) as serial_number,
                              x509_signatureHashAlgorithm(c.certificate) as signature_hash_algorithm,
                              x509_signatureKeyAlgorithm(c.certificate) as signature_key_algorithm,
                              x509_subjectName(c.certificate) as subject_name,
                              x509_name(c.certificate) as name,
                              x509_altNames(c.certificate) as alt_names
                        FROM certificate c, certificate_identity ci
                        WHERE c.id = ci.certificate_id
                             AND ci.name_type = 'dNSName'
                             AND lower(ci.name_value) = lower(%s)
                             AND x509_notAfter(c.certificate) > statement_timestamp()
                        '''
                    with psycopg2.connect("dbname=certwatch user=guest host=crt.sh".format(DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_HOST)) as conn:
                        cursor = conn.cursor(cursor_factory=psycopg2.extras.NamedTupleCursor)
                        cursor.execute(SQL, (domain_name,))

                        certificate_store = cursor.fetchall()
                        for certificate in certificate_store:
                            print(certificate.id)
                            print(certificate.common_name)
                            print(certificate.issuer_name)
                            outfile.write(json.dumps(certificate, sort_keys=True, indent=4, default=str, ensure_ascii=False))


                # query db with start and offset
                #    unique_domains = cursor.fetchall()
                #    if not unique_domains:
                #        flag = False
                #    else:
                        # do processing with your data

                #        pprint.pprint(unique_domains)


                #        outfile.write(json.dumps(unique_domains, sort_keys=True, indent=4, default=str, ensure_ascii = False))
                #        offset += limit


            except Exception as error:
                print(str(error))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    connect_to_db()
```

Comment: You are fetching twice from the cursor. Also please use global path names for your files.

Comment: Try closing the file stream.I think the missing outfile.close might be the one that is causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The line that writes to a file:

```
outfile.write(...)
```

Is protected by a `if` condition:

```
if not unique_domains:
    flag = False                    
else:
    ....
    outfile.write(...)
```

So `unique_domains` must be `True`ish.

But your line

```
unique_domains = cursor.fetchall()
```

Is **not** inside the block for the database `with` condition:

```
with psycopg2.connect("dbname=certwatch user=guest host=crt.sh".format(DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_HOST)) as conn:
```

Also you already fetched (and discarded after printing) the records in

```
for certificate in cursor.fetchall():
```

So you can't fetch them again unless you `.execute` the query again. A better idea would be to store the data in the first fetch.

Comment: Thank you for your post! I posted my new code above showing I added certificate_store = cursor.fetchall() to my code. Is this right? If not, I would greatly appreciate your help!

Comment: @bedford you're still calling `fetchall()` more than once - you should do `certificate_store = cursor.fetchall()` then use `for certificate in certificate_store`... you can't call `fetchall()` again.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I made those changes and I updated my code above. I added certificate_store = cursor.fetchall()
                    for certificate in certificate_store:

to my code but it is still not working. I would greatly appreciate your help!

Comment: @bedford it seems fine now that you're calling `fetchall` only once. But the database code is still outside the `with` block for the database connection. That means the database is closed when it runs.

Comment: I posted my updated code with the database code indented but it still doesn't work.

Comment: How is it failing now?

Comment: It gives me an error message saying "Error: login rejected am i stuck" Do you have any other suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: We need a really specific full error message output.

Comment: I just tried a similar code against my own postgresql server and it works fine. Maybe your login credentials are wrong? I don't see anything wrong with the code.

Comment: I also get another error code that says "ERROR: no more connections allowed (max_client_conn). It flips back and forth between that and the "ERROR: login rejected am i stuck" error message. I'm guessing that I'm guessing it's something to do with the syntax of my code since I wasn't getting that error message before.

Comment: Now I am not getting that error message but now but my code is still not writing to the JSON file. If you could help me get my code writing to the JSON file I would greatly appreciate it!